# How to tell if user changed a property in the view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my MVC POST routine, is there something I can look at (probably related to ModelState?) that lets me know if the user has changed any of the model properties?  In other words, has the user entered a value on the form different from the value supplied by the GET action that populated the view model and rendered the form?

Comment: No, you need to get the original again and compare the values.

Comment: That's not really the job of the handler or the controller. Assign it to an EF entity and the change-tracker may be able to help you (I'm not sure it's accessible by property).

Comment: Ok... So, in my POST routine, I assign each model variable to its associated EF entity property, then I call `dbContext.SaveChanges`.  Between updating the EF entity properties (with possibly unchanged values) and calling `SaveChanges`, how do I ask the DbContext if any values have been changed?

Comment: Does `dbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges();` do what its name and docs imply?  It looks like I should be able to query that `HasChanges` method to see if the user changed any of the original values...

Comment: Tested `dbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges()` and it seems to do just what I want: It returns true if the user has changed any of the entity values.  Thanks for giving me a swift kick in the right direction.  I'll post an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the usual scenario, the GET routine reads values from an "entity" object (a POCO wired up to a data store via EF), writes the values to a view model, and displays a view whose editors are pre-populated with values from the view model.

The user POSTs back to the POST action routine, which receives a populated view model containing the user's values.  In order to detect whether or not the user changed any of the values, update the entity and examine `DbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges()`, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> EditPersonalInfo(SomeViewModel model)
    // Get the entity record to be updated
    var user = {Get currently logged in ApplicationUser}

    // Update the entity record.  The model values may or may not be
    // identical to the existing entity values
    user.SomeProperty = model.SomeProperty;
    user.AnotherProperty = model.AnotherProperty;

    // Get the DbContext
    var db = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();

    // Have any entity values been changed?
    if (db.ChangeTracker.HasChanges()) {
         // Save the changes
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        // Tell the user the data was changed...
        <...>
    }
}
```